# How to keep highlights after close browser

Tags: javascript

I have this function to highlight words in javascript. The problem is I need to add two things:

- a way to save the highlights, so if user close browser and open again the hightlights will be preserved.
- a way to remove the highlights, by clicking on it or anything else.

Any idea how to adapt this code?

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var btn = document.body;
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var wrap = ["A"]; // nodes that should be wrapped in mark (rather than node's textContent wrapped in mark)
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

        if (!range.startContainer.isSameNode(range.endContainer)) {
            // get all nodes within the range commonAncestorContainer node
            var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
                range.commonAncestorContainer,
                NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL
            );

            var nodeList = [];
            var currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;
            while (currentNode) {
                nodeList.push(currentNode);
                currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
            }

            var start = null; // index that our selected nodes start
            var end = null; // index that our selected nodes end
            var selNodes = nodeList.filter(function (val, i) {
                // filter the node list
                var node = nodeList[i];
                start = start ?? (val.isSameNode(range.startContainer) ? i : null); // if same as start node
                end = end ?? (val.isSameNode(range.endContainer) ? i : null); // if same as end node
                var lesser = start == null || i <= start; // is before start node?
                var greater = end != null && i >= end; // is after end node?
                return (
                    !lesser &&
                    !greater &&
                    !node.isSameNode(range.endContainer.parentNode) && // node is not same as end node's parent
                    node != undefined &&
                    node != null &&
                    node.textContent.replace(/\t|\n/g, "") != "" &&
                    node.textContent.replace(/\t|\n/g, "") != undefined &&
                    !node.contains(range.endContainer) && // node does not contain end node
                    !node.isSameNode(range.endContainer.parentNode) // node is not same as end node's parent
                );
            });

            // mark node at start of selection
            var sParent = range.startContainer.parentNode;
            var sText = range.startContainer.textContent;
            var mark = document.createElement("mark");
            // wrap a tags in mark
            if (
                wrap.includes(sParent.nodeName) &&
                sText.replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "") ==
                    sText.substring(range.startOffset).replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "")
            ) {
                var node = sParent.cloneNode(true);
                mark.append(node);
                sParent.after(mark);
                sParent.remove();
            } else {
                mark.textContent = sText.substring(range.startOffset);
                range.startContainer.textContent = sText.substring(range.startOffset, -1);
                range.startContainer.after(mark);
            }

            // mark node at end of selection
            var eParent = range.endContainer.parentNode;
            // console.log("end parent: ", eParent);
            var eText = range.endContainer.textContent;
            var mark = document.createElement("mark");
            // wrap a tags in mark
            if (
                wrap.includes(eParent.nodeName) &&
                eText.replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "") ==
                    eText.substring(range.endOffset, -1).replace(/\t+|\n+/gm, "")
            ) {
                var node = eParent.cloneNode(true);
                mark.append(node);
                eParent.after(mark);
                eParent.remove();
            } else {
                mark.textContent = eText.substring(range.endOffset, -1);
                range.endContainer.textContent = eText.substring(range.endOffset);
                range.endContainer.before(mark);
            }

            // mark nodes in between start and end
            selNodes.forEach(function (val, idx) {
                var currentNode = selNodes[idx];
                var mark = document.createElement("mark");
                if (currentNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    // if text node, insert mark after node and remove node
                    mark.textContent = currentNode.textContent;
                    currentNode.after(mark);
                    currentNode.remove();
                } else {
                    if (wrap.includes(currentNode.nodeName)) {
                        var node = currentNode.cloneNode(true);
                        mark.append(node);
                        currentNode.after(mark);
                        currentNode.remove();
                    } else {
                        // reset the node's html and append mark
                        mark.textContent = currentNode.textContent;
                        currentNode.innerHTML = "";
                        currentNode.appendChild(mark);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            var parentNode = range.startContainer.parentNode;
            var mark = document.createElement("mark");
            if (wrap.includes(parentNode.nodeName)) {
                var node = parentNode.cloneNode(true);
                node.textContent = sel.toString();
                mark.append(node);
                parentNode.after(mark);
                parentNode.remove();
            } else {
                var sText = document.createTextNode(
                    range.startContainer.textContent
                        .substring(range.startOffset, -1)
                        .toString()
                );
                var eText = document.createTextNode(
                    range.endContainer.textContent.substring(range.endOffset).toString()
                );
                mark.textContent = sel.toString();
                range.startContainer.after(eText);
                range.startContainer.after(mark);
                range.startContainer.after(sText);
                range.startContainer.remove();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Save the highlighting information in `localStorage`.

Comment: But since you can't save references to DOM elements in LS, you'll need to come up with some way to encode the highlighting so you can find the same elements when it's reloaded. This seems like a hard problem, since the page content can change between reloads.

Comment: The information to be saved should be: selector, start highlight, end highlight, exact text. The first three are useful to find the text, the last one is useful to check whether the text has changed in the while

Comment: Thanks for the answers, friend! Yeah, it is a quite hard thing to program.

Answer (score -5):

There is no way to solve that  you may need to change your browser  **BUT IF YOU WANT** You can contact your browser adminstrator ️ *And may he will help!!*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).